# In how many ways can you give out $12$ apples to $5$ unique children?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you give out $12$ apples to $5$ unique children? By unique we mean that if the child A gets all the apples it is not the same as if the child B gets all the apples.

I have been struggling at this for a while as I don't have any idea how to approach these types of problems.

This has been for certain asked before (or at least a similar question) but I haven't found any. (Most likely my poor English math vocab is to blame here.) So, if you find one, please link it.

Comment: Do you require all $5$ children to receive at least $1$ apple each (or in other words, the map from apples to children to be surjective)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang No, it might as well be that one child gets all of them.

Comment: If there is no restriction on how much each child should or should not get, then you can use the stars and bars method (https://youtu.be/UTCScjoPymA) as @5201314 pointed out. What you basically do is divide the $12$ apples into $5$ groups (here, children) using $4$ dividers. Think of the apples and dividers as one entity. Place them in a row. You'll get $16$ of them. Now from that $16$, choose $4$ of them to be dividers. You can do that in $\binom{16}{4}$ ways. This is nothing but the number of unique distributions.

Comment: Thank you. Really interesting and intuitive method of solving these.

Comment: See also [this separate Stars and Bars article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/).

Comment: All children are unique.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $5^{12}=244140625$, the number of maps from a set with $12$ elements (apples, in this case) to a set with $5$ elements (children, in this case). Note that having a child receiving no apple at all is allowed, as the map is not required to be surjective.

Comment: Your answer assumes that not only are the children unique, but the apples are also unique.  That is, your answer would be correct if the apples were tagged Apple-1, Apple-2, ..., Apple-12.  Since it is assumed that the apples are not unique, you are over-counting Apple-1 goes to person-1, Apple-2 goes to person-2 as distinct from Apple-2 goes to person-1, Apple-1 goes to person-2.  This is actually a [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) problem.